# change the order of Multilevel list of Office Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I want to reverse the order of section and subsection in the Multilevel list of Office Word.

for example:

```
1.
   1.1
   2.1
   3.1
2.
   1.2
   2.2
   3.2
```

can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter the Outline view by clicking

View > Outline

[image: How to enter outline view]

2. Drag the section handle to the correct location

Before:

[image: Multi-level heading example A]

After:

[image: Multi=level heading example B]

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2013, I can make this happen by customizing the multilevel list. Other modern versions of Word should be very similar.

In the `Paragraph` section of the `Home` tab of the ribbon, select the Multilevel list button, then select `Define New Multilevel List...`.

Then follow this pattern:

- Select Level 1 in the "Click level to modify" list.
- Clear out the "Enter formatting for number:" box.
- Select "1, 2, 3, …" from the "Number style for this level:" box.
- Add a period to the end of the "Enter formatting for number:", if desired.
- Select Level 2 in the "Click level to modify" list.
- Clear out the "Enter formatting for number:" box.
- Select "Level 1" in the "Include level number from:" box.
- Move the cursor to the beginning of the "Enter formatting for number:" box.
- Select "1, 2, 3, …" from the "Number style for this level:" box.
- Add a period (or other desired separator) between the 1's that are now in the "Enter formatting for number:" box. Add a period to the end, if desired.
- Select Level 3 in the "Click level to modify" list.
- Clear out the "Enter formatting for number:" box.
- Select "Level 1" in the "Include level number from:" box.
- Move the cursor to the beginning of the "Enter formatting for number:" box.
- Select "Level 2" in the "Include level number from:" box.
- Move the cursor to the beginning of the "Enter formatting for number:" box.
- Select "1, 2, 3, …" from the "Number style for this level:" box.
- Add a period (or other desired separator) between the 1's that are now in the "Enter formatting for number:" box. Add a period to the end, if desired.
- Repeat as necessary if you want more than three levels.